# SQL PIVOT Multiple Records to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

PIVOT and other advanced SQL are very new to me.  My experience with SQL is limited to basic Queries and Joins.  I've been trying to wrap my head around using these tools and have scheduled training to advance my education in SQL.

In the meantime I am hoping to get some guidance from the SO community.

I have a table that contains tens of thousands of records that I need to generate a special report for.  The table can have many records for a single person, but each record is obviously a unique record with unique information.

The report generation tool will be requesting the data for a specific person for a specific time period.  This will generally list 1-7 records.  I believe I need to PIVOT to show each record as column for each person.

I have attached an image to try and illustrate the start point and desired output.  My co-worker and I have spent time trying to do this, he has used PIVOT, but not in a few years as he has not needed it recently.

[image: Illustration of input and desired output]

If PIVOT is not the correct solution for this I understand, but I want to rule it out if it is not.  I can do what I want programmatically pretty easily I think, but doing this work on the DB server instead of in the application would significantly reduce report generation time.

I hope to find some clarity/assistance here as I'm completely stumped.

Comment: there are hundreds of questions about sql server pivoting on the site, have you tried looking at similar posts?

Comment: Why does your desired result have columns named `Interim`, `Summative`, and `Overall`?   What is the logic behind these column names?   They certainly didn't come from the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make use of dynamic SQL to achieve desired results since the possible values on which the dataset should be pivoted on is unknown at the time of execution. You are also pivoting on multiple columns `[Observation]` & `[Observer]` which means you will either have to make use of a `CASE` statement with a `GROUP BY` clause or combine the two columns in question into a single pivot value column. What complicates this query further is the fact that the `[Type]` will seems to impact on how the results should be displayed.

I have created an example of how you can achieve your desired results below. I made the following assumptions:

- Value of type field is defined as follow: 1 = Observation, 2 =
  Interim, 3 = Summative, 6 = Overall
- Based on your sample output only one occurrence of an Interim, Summative and Overall observations is expected in pivoted results.
- Based on your sample output the Observer is not displayed for Interim, Summative and Overall observations

Example:

```
-- Create some sample data
DECLARE @Observations TABLE
(
     [Name]         NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,[Building]     NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,[Observation]  DATETIME
    ,[Observer]     NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,[Type]         INT
);

INSERT INTO @Observations
SELECT 'Doe, John', 'HQ', '01/01/2017', 'Doe, Jack', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Doe, John', 'HQ', '02/01/2017', 'Doe, Jack', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Doe, John', 'HQ', '03/01/2017', 'Doe, Jack', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Doe, John', 'HQ', '04/01/2017', 'Doe, Jack', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Doe, John', 'HQ', '05/01/2017', 'Doe, Jack', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Doe, John', 'HQ', '06/01/2017', 'Doe, Jack', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Doe, John', 'HQ', '07/01/2017', 'Doe, Jack', 6;

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @selectClause NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #IntermResults
(
     [Name]         NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL       
    ,[Building]     NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL   
    ,[PivotValue]   NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL   
    ,[PivotID]      NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,[Observation]  DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,[OrderRank]    INT NOT NULL
)

-- Prepare the source data to make pivoting into desired format easier and store results into an interim temporary table.
;WITH ObservationsCTE
AS
(
    SELECT   [Name]         
            ,[Building]     
            ,[Observation]  
            ,[Observer]     
            ,[Type]
            ,(  
                CASE [Type]
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'Observation'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'Interim'
                    WHEN 3 THEN 'Summative'
                    WHEN 6 THEN 'Overall'
                    ELSE 'UNKNOW'
                END
             ) AS [ObservationType] -- Give descriptive values to Type column’s values. This will be used to help generate pivot table column names.
    FROM    @Observations   
), ObservationsWithPivotIDs
AS
(
    SELECT   TOP 1000
             [Name]         
            ,[Building]     
            ,CAST([Observation] AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS [PivotValue] -- Pivot value effectively combines the Observation & Observer column to help simplify the pivot query.
            ,'Observation' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Observation]) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS [PivotID] -- Create a pivot id that will be used to generate pivoted columns.
            ,[Observation]
            ,1 AS [OrderRank] -- use this field to help order records.
    FROM    ObservationsCTE
    WHERE   [Type] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   TOP 1000
             [Name]         
            ,[Building]     
            ,[Observer] AS [PivotValue] -- Pivot value effectively combines the Observation & Observer column to help simplify the pivot query.
            ,'Observer' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Observation]) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS [PivotID] -- Create a pivot id that will be used to generate pivoted columns.
            ,[Observation]
            ,2 AS [OrderRank] -- use this field to help order records.
    FROM    ObservationsCTE
    WHERE   [Type] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   TOP 1000
             [Name]         
            ,[Building]     
            ,CAST([Observation] AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS [PivotValue] -- Pivot value effectively combines the Observation & Observer column to help simplify the pivot query.
            ,[ObservationType]  AS [PivotID]
            ,[Observation]
            ,1 AS [OrderRank] -- use this field to help order records.
    FROM    ObservationsCTE
    WHERE   [Type] <> 1
)
INSERT INTO #IntermResults  -- Insert the results into an intermediate table.
(
     [Name]         
    ,[Building]     
    ,[PivotValue]   
    ,[PivotID]      
    ,[Observation]  
    ,[OrderRank]    
)
SELECT   [Name]         
        ,[Building]     
        ,[PivotValue]   
        ,[PivotID]      
        ,[Observation]  
        ,[OrderRank]    
FROM    ObservationsWithPivotIDs

-- Determine what columns will be created for the pivot
SELECT   @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME([PivotID])
        ,@selectClause += N', ' + (CASE [OrderRank]
                                        WHEN  1 THEN 'CAST(' + QUOTENAME([PivotID]) + ' AS DATETIME) AS ' + QUOTENAME([PivotID])
                                        ELSE [PivotID] 
                                    END)
FROM     #IntermResults
ORDER BY [Observation], [OrderRank]

-- Create dynamic query to create the pivot
SET @sql = N'
SELECT [Name], [Building], ' + STUFF(@selectClause, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM (
        SELECT  [Name]
                ,[Building]
                ,[PivotValue]
                ,[PivotID]
        FROM    #IntermResults
    ) i
PIVOT
(
  MAX([PivotValue]) FOR [PivotID] IN ('
  + STUFF(@columns, 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';

PRINT @sql;
-- Execute dynamic pivot query
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
-- Drop intermediate results
DROP TABLE #IntermResults
```

Comment: The amount of detail in your post is awesome.  I will review your example and see if I can even vaguely understand and implement it in our environment.

If this does indeed help me achieve the results I desire then you've been a huge help.  At first glance... I feel like I should do this programmatically in our application instead of in the DB, but this is purely due to my lack of SQL knowledge/understanding.

Comment: @RoyDePhillip glad I could help. If you can perform the pivot within your application, then I recommend that you do that. Dynamic SQL queries tend to be harder to debug, maintain and exposes you to potential SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of an output you should use `PIVOT` with dynamic sql. There is an good example of PIVOT-UNPIVOT and using dynamic sql with PIVOT in this post [Insert column alias from table to query results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46443185/5243847). You can look for this post for further information about PIVOT and UNPIVOT [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)